# IE10 suggests sites I have never visited

Tags: internet-explorer-10

I'm running Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 8 RTM and just saw, that IE suggest some sites when entering something in the address bar. That wouldn't surprise me at all, if I had ever visited these sites, but I haven't. To ensure that no ads have injected these sites into my browsing history, I've deleted my history and cookies without preserving my *favourite website data*. I also double checked that *suggested sites* feature is turned off.
But even after cleaning my history these sites show up.

Now I'm little concerned what is causing this. Did Microsoft add these sites by default to make some money (all these sites are commercial) or do I already got some nasty adware?

Edit: Search suggestion are disabled too.

[image: sites IE suggests when typing a in the address bar]

Comment: Just checked my W8 IE10, does the same thing. I got AOL, Amazon and AT&T and I have not visited any of these sites, its advertising, jerks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are called "Search Suggestions", depending on what search provider you have chosen for IE10 what it will return, you should be able to turn off search suggestions for your default search provider in add-ons. I tried disabling everything for Bing my default search provider and it does not change anything, it still suggests, so I assume it is broken or is not suggested sites causing this behavior.

[image]

.

Maybe it is not suggested sites, doing the following disables that behavior,

Internet Options > Content Tab > AutoComplete settings

uncheck "Suggesting URL's" box.

Even though I have NEVER visited anything it shows me, its SPAM from Microsoft.

Note:
You must disable autocomplete (suggesting URLs) and suggestions for your default search provider to stop all suggestions in the URL bar. I disabled auto complete and turned on suggestions for my Google default search provider and the suggestions changed to something else, so the autocomplete setting overrides the add-on setting regardless of which provider you use, this has to be a bug or worse Microsoft being really bad, say it ain't so!

.

[image]

Comment: I've already disabled search suggestions. Forgot to mention it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Jay check my edit.

Comment: What tool did you use to make those nice red pointers in the images?